# Android database custom listview open to multiple activities

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

[image]

I found this app that uses a database with multiple tables. This here is a listview that saves incomes and expenses but they are in different activities. Does anyone knows how can I make this kind of listview?

Comment: This is way too broad. You need to start your project and post a more specific question complete with relevant code and errors, if any.

Comment: questions with upvoted and accepted questions should not be marked as "too broad" even if it is possible to find evidence as how they may violate a rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple .for first you need to create class extend listActivity like this :
     public class seasones extends ListActivity {

```
private database db;
private String[] Name;
private String[] Teedad;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.seasone);
    db = new database(this);


    refresher();
    setListAdapter(new listview ());

}
```

and Xml for this like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/main_txt_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ListView
      android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
  </ListView>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

please notice to android:id="@android:id/list" It's very important.
OK.
 Now we create class for custom layout for each row . for first create class and extend ArrayAdapter .

```
  class listview extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public listview (){
        super(seasones.this,R.layout.raw_seasone,Name);

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater in = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = in.inflate(R.layout.raw_seasone, parent,false);

        TextView name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name_season);
        TextView teedad = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.teedad_dastan);

        name.setText(Name [position]);
        teedad.setText(Teedad [position]);



        return (row);
    }
```

for this activity we create a layout file like this :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/teedad_dastan"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
       android:text="Small Text"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/name_season"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/teedad_dastan"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
       android:text="Large Text"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

I use refresher(); method for fill array from database .and use setListAdapter(new listview ()); for fill each row with custom layout .